# How to insert many source tables into one destination table using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

I have a connection manager (oledb) that points to a folder that has 20 dbf files. All the dbf files have the same schema. Just the data are for specific entities. I want to take all the data from the 20 dbf files and insert them into one table (in sql server). What tasks enables me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create "For each loop" container, to write each file path to variable f.e. `@fp`
After that, you put inside DataFlow task and configure the [connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337084.aspx) 
After, you should create another variable like `@table` (substring your `@fp`,to only file name) and put this variable in DataFlow task in source table.
[ready example](http://visakhm.blogspot.ru/2013/08/importing-dbf-files-to-ssis.html)